# Socket listening TCP. Can see data received on wireshark, but not reaching port. C#

Tags: c#, sockets, wireshark

I am trying to use an asynchronous TCP listener in C#. Code picked up as is from -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example.

My problem is, every once in a while I see (WireShark) that packets (messages) have arrived. But my application is not able to read that data. Data simply does not reach my application listening on the port.

There is another program that I have written for the same application (using different logic) which seems to run smoothly everywhere except at the **above** location where it gives the following error intermittently (probably for the same messages wherein the earlier program fails to read the data).

*System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)*

I should also mention that mostly only certain types of messages fail to reach the application.

Can someone please guide me to see what the problem is so that I can resolve it?

Comment: Does wireshark show any errors?  There are a few reasons.  You could have a CRC error so the packet is thrown away by the interface in PC.  Is wireshark running on PC that is receiving data or another PC.  Another application is registered for the port.  From cmd.exe use >netstat -a and check status of the port.  You could have two machines with the same IP address.  Disconnect PC fromnetwork and then try ping from another machine. If you get a response than you have duplicate IP addresses.

Comment: Does Wireshark show any errors? -: NO. The packet reaches WireShark on the SAME PC, so obviously it is not being thrown away by the interface. NO other application is using the port. NO two machines have the same IP address.

Comment: Wireshark replaces PCAP and will see the CRC errors while the application doesn't.  You need a route and a return route.  If may be the return route is failing.  What type of messages are failing?  often in these cases I use Ping and try PIN from both client and server.  If ping works in one direction and not the other it may be the mask on the interfaced that is blocking the return route.

Comment: Thanks. But routes are fine. Else ALL messages would have failed. Obviously, PING is fine too. How do I check if there is a CRC error?

Comment: Should be in the wireshark details.  What type message are failing?  Are they longer messages?  if an error is occurring I usually like test ping with lots of data.  Use Ping -t -l 65500 IP

Comment: What port number are yo using?  You should use a port number above 1000. Port numbers below 1000 are reserved for protocols which may get blocked by a virus checker or firewall.

Comment: Long messages : Read bugger length 4096. Pretty sure NO message is longer than that since they are ISO 8583 standard messages. Port no : 45145.

Comment: I think I found issue "IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];"  Array zero is usually these days IPV6 and array one is IVP4.  Try changing from zero to one.

Comment: Thanks very much. Will try that.